# Efficient way to Query a Delimited Varchar Field in SQL

Tags: sql

I have an SQL Server 2005 table that has a varchar(250) field which contains keywords that I will use for searching purposes.  I can't change the design.  The data looks like this...

> Personal, Property, Cost, Endorsement

What is the most efficient way to run search queries against these keywords?  The only thing I can think of is this...

```
WHERE Keywords LIKE '%endorse%'
```

Comment: Do you allow commas in the search?

Comment: Yes, commas are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since normalization is not an option, the next best option is going to be to configure and use Full Text Search. This will maintain an internal search index that will make it very easy for you to search within your data.

The problem with solutions like LIKE '%pattern%' is that this will produce a full table scan (or maybe a full index scan) that could produce locks on a large amount of the data in your table, which will slow down any operations that hit the table in question.

Comment: Looks like the right answer... but if FTI is not already enabled/configured/whatever in the system, would adding it in be as much a deal-breaker as modifying the table structure?

Comment: With SQL Server 2005 you will have to get a DBA to install the FTS feature, so depending on the situation this could present difficulties. Once FTS is installed, creating the indexes is simple. This could be an easier sell than normalization, though, because other applications that access the source data won't need to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  How do I configure Full Text Search?  Can you link me up, please?

Comment: Installation instructions can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142490(SQL.90).aspx

And here's a big list of "how to" topics on FTS from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142503(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think we will finally be installing this soon!!

Answer (score 1):

the most efficient way is to normalize your db design. never store CSV values into a single cell.
other than using like you might consider full text search.

Comment: are you quite sure about it being worthless? i gave you the only other valid option you can use. patindex and all other stuff is just like "Like"

Comment: Outside of normalization (which isn't an option to OP), and PATINDEX, FTS is the other performant option. FTS is, honestly, probably the best option since it is going to be optimized for the volume of data you have and most likely will return better results in less time and with fewer I/O operations than PATINDEX.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PATINDEX()

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT PATINDEX('%ensure%',DocumentSummary)
FROM Production.Document
WHERE DocumentID = 3;
GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think this is more efficient than LIKE?

Comment: According to the first comment here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/is-patindex-faster-than-like.aspx, Full Text indexing might be an even better way to go. 
 Full Text: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx